# Best way to invoke method inhereted from Base class : use this , super or call implicitly

Tags: java, inheritance

I think it's not very useful question, but i think someone can say smth critical.

```
public class Base{
    public void boo(){}
}

public class Derivative extends Base{

1:public void useBoo(){
    boo();
}

2:public void useBoo(){
    this.boo();
}

3:public void useBoo(){
    super.boo();
}
}
```

**[EDIT]**

The reason why I asked this question : to avoid recompilation or name confusion in future. And make code more readability and flexable to future changes.

Comment: `boo()` and `this.boo()` are same, while `super.boo()` is a superclass method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use 1 and 2 (in my case I prefer 2, I like to be explicit about my intentions)

```
public void useBoo(){
    this.boo();
}
```

I wouldn't use 3 because it means something else semantically, remember that `Derivative` can also be extended, and `boo()` may be overridden further down the class hierarchy, and unless you specifically want to call `Base.boo()` you shouldn't use the `super` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The best one to use is the one you feel is clearest.

BTW: The first example will behave different to the third example, if you add a `boo` method to Derived.

Comment: The best of the first two depends on clarity. The best between the first two and the latter depends on intent.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer, Well put. What I would have liked to have said is; you should make your intent clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that the method invoked is the super class method, definitely use super:

```
super.boo();
```

If you want to use a method defined in the current class and if this is not present use the super method use:

```
this.boo();
//or
boo();
```

Personally in the second case, if the class is part of a hierarchy, I prefer to explicitly use this.boo() because it's more clear reading the code, to understand where the method is supposed to be. But it's my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the first two, unless you explicitly want to limit the call to the superclass implementation.

When you override a superclass method, and want to include the behavior of the superclass method, use the third.

Elsewhere, if you use the third, and later you or someone else overrides the superclass implementation of boo() -- in this class or a subclass -- then useBoo() will not use the override. This is usually undesirable except in the override of boo() itself.

Examples:

```
/** Extends boo method. */
public void boo(){
    super.boo();   // Good: you explicitly want to call the superclass method, not call this method again.
}

public void doSomethingThatInvolvesBoo() {
    boo();        // Good -- will call this object's implementation,
                  // even if this is a subclass, even if there are code changes later.
    this.boo();   // Good (and equivalent to simply calling boo()).
    super.boo():  // Usually bad.
}
```

Comment: -1: Half of this answer is not relevant to the question. The question is "Best way to invoke method inhereted from Base class". We do not want to 'do something that involves boo()', we want to **call boo() which is a method in the super class**.

Comment: Engaging in vote retribution is out of place on StackOverflow. Note that the question does not specify whether the intent is to call a superclass method, or to call a method that happens to be currently defined in the superclass. Hence the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping you from just calling boo()? Or have you overridden it in your own code?
1 and 2 do the same thing, 3 calls the method of Base.

edit: as Simeon said, using super would make it very clear you are calling the method from the Base class.

Comment: By this tyme i write boo(). But I whant to know if there is situation that force to use some of case (from 1-3). May be to avoid recompilation in future or something else. There is might be smth exotic in java specification. It's just consultation. If there is no reason for one of approach it will ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Having readability in mind `super` is probably the best because it says **here I'm invoking a method from the super class**.

While with `this` you could wonder 'where the hell is this method .. oh ok its in the super class'

Comment: The intent matters more than the current implementation. The implementation may change in the future, with method overrides. Finding a method definition is trivial in modern IDEs.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer What might happen in the future is not a concern of this question, nor mine, nor should be yours IMHO :) The question is "Best way to invoke method inhereted from Base class". If we override the method we're no longer discussing the scope of the question. I actually thought this to be obvious.

Comment: the question explicitly asks about flexibility for changes.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question Oleksandr asked.  He wants to invoke a method from the base class in a class that overrides the base class method.  He has no choice but to use super.

Comment: @emory, the question does not specify that the derived class overrides the base class method. It does specify that the method is inherited -- but this is not the same as *wanting* to invoke the superclass method.